# Error in change specification. Can't update committed change

Tags: perforce

In Perforce we are attempting to submit a single file and seeing an unexpected error.  This after encountering a problem which locked all the submitted files in the project.  We unlocked the files and are attempting to submit subsets of the full changelist.  We are now seeing the following problem.

When we submit *file A*, the 'submit changelist' dialog displays.  In the 'choose files to submit' list *file A* is not displayed, but *file B* (which was not selected to be submitted) is displayed.  If we continue and select submit we receive the error:

> Error in change specification. Can't update committed change <######>.

The committed change refers to when *file B* was checked in.

What could be wrong here and what can be done to fix it?

Comment: Sounds like a potential bug. You should post on our forums or contact support we can help you out.